# How to get ember.js module work in play framework

Tags: ember.js, playframework-2.0

I developed a little web app and now I'm trying ti merge the server-side code deployed under Play! framework with my client-side code made with Ember.js.

I found this module https://github.com/krumpi/play-emberjs
on Play! web site but I can't get it to work, it gives me this error

sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.ketalo.play.plugins#emberjs;0.4.0-SNAPSHOT: not found

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: which version of ember.js have you used for your ember app? and which version is defined by the play framework?

Comment: I used Ember 1.0.0-rc6 and I followed the link from Play! to github and used the version for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using ember rc6 than you need to define the right snapshot.
As stated in the docs:

> version 0.4.0-SNAPSHOT Include support for ember.js 1.0 rc6

for ember rc6 you will need snapshot `0.4.0`. But the error you get is suggesting that you are using snapshot `0.1.0`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, my typoo. I copied the wrong error message. I managed to get to snapshot 0.4.0 but it sill says me :sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.ketalo.play.plugins#emberjs;0.4.0-SNAPSHOT: not found

Comment: strange, after looking here: https://github.com/krumpi/play-emberjs/blob/master/sample-1.0.0-rc.6/project/plugins.sbt and following the repo url `http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/` I couldn't find any `com.ketalo.play.plugins` I guess this is the spot where it is failing

Answer (score 2):

There is a mistake in the samples

The plugins.sbt needs to include a reference to the sonatatype repository:

```
 // Repository for sonata snapshots
 resolvers += "Sonatype snapshots" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
```